# Trying to create a navbar with a menu dropdown, but my menu items seem to not want to appear or they are hidden inside my parent container

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation

I'm creating a simple navbar which I want to be responsive. My current problem is that I'm trying to have a dropdown menu (pulled this from W3Schools) on one of the menu items, and when I hover none of the items are appearing but they are showing when I inspect them.

I've tried applying z-index and changing the position to relative but nothing is working properly.

```
   <div class="navwrap">
      <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
         <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
         <a href="#news">News</a>
         <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
         <a href="#about">About</a>
         <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
         </a>
         <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
               <a href="#">Link 1</a>
               <a href="#">Link 2</a>
               <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

*CSS*

```
.navwrap{}
.topnav {
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: #333;

   .dropdown {
      button.dropbtn {

      }
      .dropdown-content {}
   }
   .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
   }
 }

 .topnav a {
   float: left;
   display: block;
   color: #f2f2f2;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 14px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 17px;
 }

 .topnav a:hover {
   background-color: #ddd;
   color: black;
 }

 .active {
   background-color: #4CAF50;
   color: white;
 }

 .topnav .icon {
   display: none;
 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
   .topnav a.icon {
     float: right;
     display: block;
   }
 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
   .topnav.responsive .icon {
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     top: 0;
   }
   .topnav.responsive a {
     float: none;
     display: block;
     text-align: left;
   }
 }
//Navigation Dropdown
.dropbtn {
   background-color: #4CAF50;
   color: white;
   padding: 16px;
   font-size: 16px;
   border: none;
}

.dropdown {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   background-color: #f1f1f1;
   min-width: 160px;
   box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
   color: black;
   padding: 12px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
   background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
   display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
   background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

*JAVASCRIPT*

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
      x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
      x.className = "topnav";
    }
  }
```

should have navbar with my 'dropdown' menu item with a dropdown.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
.navwrap {}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  .dropdown {
    button.dropbtn {}
    .dropdown-content {}
  }
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
  }
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

//Navigation Dropdown
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<!-- NAVIGATION -->
<div class="navwrap">
  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like `overflow: hidden;` is the problem here, which hide content that exceed the container boundaries.

Comment: Instant fix. Now that makes me feel like an idiot haha. Thanks @sn3p !

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

`overflow: hidden` needs to be `visible`

Comment: `visible` is the default, so could also remove it